# UncaughtException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am getting the following error while injecting `ServiceGenerator.class`.

I am trying to inject `ServiceGenerator.Class` from `SignUpActivity.Class` mainly used for retrofit api services generation and depends on `Retrofit.Builder` instance injected via Constructor injection that I have exposed from my `ApplicationComponent.Class`.

**SignUpActivity.Class**

```
Public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Inject
  ServiceGenerator serviceGenerator;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    AppGenerator.getPresenterComponent().inject(this);

  }

  private void saveMobileNumberService(String mNumber) {

        MobileNumberService mobileService =
                serviceGenerator.createService(MobileNumberService.class);

        ..

  }

}
```

**ServiceGenerator.Class**

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
  private static Retrofit.Builder builder;

  @Inject
  public ServiceGenerator(Retrofit.Builder builder) {
    this.builder = builder;

  }

  private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

  public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);

  }

}
```

**NetModule.class**

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    ....

    @Singleton
    @Provides
      ServiceGenerator provideServiceGenerator(Retrofit.Builder builder) {
      return new ServiceGenerator(builder);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
      Retrofit.Builder provideRetrofitBuilder() {
      Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
      return retrofitBuilder;
    }

}
```

**ApplicationComponent.Class**

```
@Singleton
@Component( modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class} )

public interface ApplicationComponent {

  ..

  Retrofit.Builder exposeRetrofit();
  ServiceGenerator exposeServiceGenerator();

}
```

**PresentationComponent.Class**

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = PresentationModule.class, dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class)

public interface PresenterComponent {
    void inject (SignUpActivity signUpActivity);
}
```

**Error**

I am getting the following error at runtime.

```
UncaughtException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                             at com.project.android.dependencies.modules.NetModule.provideServiceGenerator(NetModule.java:80)
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.modules.NetModule_ProvideServiceGeneratorFactory.get(NetModule_ProvideServiceGeneratorFactory.java:26)
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.modules.NetModule_ProvideServiceGeneratorFactory.get(NetModule_ProvideServiceGeneratorFactory.java:10)
                                                                        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.components.DaggerApplicationComponent.exposeServiceGenerator(DaggerApplicationComponent.java:120)
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.components.DaggerPresenterComponent$com_project_android_dependencies_components_ApplicationComponent_exposeServiceGenerator.get(DaggerPresenterComponent.java:327)
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.components.DaggerPresenterComponent$com_project_android_dependencies_components_ApplicationComponent_exposeServiceGenerator.get(DaggerPresenterComponent.java:314)
                                                                        at com.project.android.presentation.frameworks.onboarding.SignUpActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(SignUpActivity_MembersInjector.java:26)
                                                                        at com.project.android.presentation.frameworks.onboarding.SignUpActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(SignUpActivity_MembersInjector.java:8)
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.components.DaggerPresenterComponent.inject(DaggerPresenterComponent.java:162)
                                                                        at com.project.android.presentation.frameworks.onboarding.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:79)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6119)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:183)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'retrofit2.Retrofit retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build()' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.project.android.presentation.entrypoints.ServiceGenerator.<clinit>(ServiceGenerator.java:47)
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.modules.NetModule.provideServiceGenerator(NetModule.java:80) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.modules.NetModule_ProvideServiceGeneratorFactory.get(NetModule_ProvideServiceGeneratorFactory.java:26) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.modules.NetModule_ProvideServiceGeneratorFactory.get(NetModule_ProvideServiceGeneratorFactory.java:10) 
                                                                        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.components.DaggerApplicationComponent.exposeServiceGenerator(DaggerApplicationComponent.java:120) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.components.DaggerPresenterComponent$com_yangout_android_dependencies_components_ApplicationComponent_exposeServiceGenerator.get(DaggerPresenterComponent.java:327) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.components.DaggerPresenterComponent$com_yangout_android_dependencies_components_ApplicationComponent_exposeServiceGenerator.get(DaggerPresenterComponent.java:314) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.presentation.frameworks.onboarding.SignUpActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(SignUpActivity_MembersInjector.java:26) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.presentation.frameworks.onboarding.SignUpActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(SignUpActivity_MembersInjector.java:8) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.dependencies.components.DaggerPresenterComponent.inject(DaggerPresenterComponent.java:162) 
                                                                        at com.project.android.presentation.frameworks.onboarding.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:79) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6119) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:183) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

I have exposed `ServiceGenerator.Class` from `ApplicationComponent.Class` and using `PresentationComponent.Class` to inject from `SignUpActivity.Class`. I am struggling to figure it out why I am getting this `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: Look at the stack trace, there's a null pointer exception in there. Check your retrofit builder, apparently it's `null`

Comment: I am providing `Retrofit.Builder builder` to `ServiceGenerator` constructor from `NetModule.class`. Should I use @Inject before?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I have provided `Retrofit.Builder builder` in `NetModule.Class` and using the same as constructor injection for `ServiceGenerator.Class`. why is it still null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your `ServiceGenerator` (see comments):

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
  private static Retrofit.Builder builder; //no!! use Dagger 2 @Singletons instead

  @Inject
  public ServiceGenerator(Retrofit.Builder builder) {
    this.builder = builder;

  }

  private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build(); //no! don't do this

  public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);

  }
}
```

The `builder.build()` will be called before the Dagger 2 has provided the `Builder` through the constructor hence the null pointer exception.

Maintaining a static reference to `Retrofit` inside the `ServiceGenerator` is probably not the solution you want. Dependency injection and roll-your-own static singleton caching are like elves and dwarves - they don't co-exist well.

In fact, the whole `ServiceGenerator` is an extra layer of redirection that you probably don't need.

Why not configure Dagger 2 to provide `Retrofit` instead of `Retrofit.Builder`? Then you will not need to manage the instance of Retrofit yourself using the static field:

```
 @Singleton
 @Provides
  Retrofit provideRetrofit() {
  return new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .build();
  }
```

Then if you still need the `ServiceGenerator` it would be much simpler:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    public ServiceGenerator(Retrofit retrofit) {
        this.retrofit = retrofit;
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David, your proposed solution works like charm after removing static from `createService()` method as `retrofit` instance is non-static. However, I have couple of followup questions based on your explanations. 1. Is it not true, Dagger in case of construction injection first makes sure to generate `Retrofit.Builder` instance and then call `builder.build()` 2. The reason I wanted to use builder instead of retrofit is because I wanted to add interceptors for few api calls but that I can also do by @Named

Comment: Hi @Ranjan if you use constructor injection then the dependencies will be provisioned by Dagger 2 in the constructor but static initialization falls outside the scope of what Dagger 2 can do. For your second question yes you can use multiple instances of Retrofit for that purpose if you want. You can still provide the Retrofit.Builder in your module and then you can have separate `@Provides` methods for the different instances

Answer (score 2):

Update Retrofit 2.8.1. it's resolved now.